# Instantiate UI elements by name

Tags: string, actionscript-3, user-interface

I would like to know if its possible, to use a string in order to create a UI element.
I think many people have this kind of problem, they want an easy setup in flash to generate a dynamic UI, through code.

It should look like this (pseudo code):

```
addToStage("Button","add");
addToStage("TextInput","name");

private function addToStage ( o : Object, str : String ) : void {
    var myItem : o = new o();
    addchild ( myItem );
}
```

Of course, the above sample does not work, but is there a possibility to implement that kind of behavior?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do that using the function `getDefinitionByName`, something like:

```
var UiButton:Class = getDefinitionByName("spark.components.Button") as Class;
var sparkButton = new UiButton("SpecialButton") as Button;
```

Comment: Note that you have to compile in your definition of Button anyway, so you might as well just refer to it in a more hard coded, less error-prone way.

Comment: So what hard coded, less error-prone way solution you will refer to?